# Many questions about socketio

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I would say my english is not the best but I will try my best.
So I have a few questions about socketIO because since few days I can't move on with my project. I can't find any good information because it is either too old, something doesn't work, etc.

I want to start the game when player clicks a start button. And then:
1. If he is first on the website I want him on click start, create a room and join the room.
2. If the second player clicks start he will join to to first room.
3. When the third player clicks start I want him to create another room and join that room.
4. If the first room has a space left because the player two left the game I want the next guy who wants play to join any room where there is one slot left.
5. So I want as many as I can create rooms with only two slots.
6. When both players leave room I want to delete that room.

Ok, I hope you understand what I mean. I spent the last 20 hours trying to do that but I can't. I don't know. I've been learning programming for a month I think and as a first project I don't wanna create something simple. But this game is going to be simple.

So I got code here. Could you say how can I do that - just for the testing

When someone visits the site I want him to join roomOne. Then check if length of the roomOne is 2 I want next guys who visits the website create and join another room.

io.on('connection', (sock) => {

```
sock.join('RoomOne', function () {

})

console.log(sock.adapter.rooms['RoomOne'].length);
```

})

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not the place to ask for a tutorial, nor the place to find free programmers**. Your question should _show_ that you've put some efford into solving your own problem and should be answerable without writing half a book.

Comment: That being said: As a beginner programmer, working with websockets and / or multiplayer games is definitely not something you should undertake. You're really underestimating how extremely complicated this will be. Sure, libraries make it look quite simple because they do most of the work for you. But in the end it just provides you with the tools you're going to need. The logic is still up to you. If you really must go down this path, I would start with a chatsystem instead.